# Read a file untill a string in matched

Tags: regex, string, file, powershell

My input file contains:

```
Startoffile

 Host status

 Server1

 Server2

 Server3

 Pending Device
 Device1 

 Device2

 ..

 Devic100
Endoffile
```

How to write a simple PowerShell script which will read the files until the line "Pending Device"?

Comment: You did not even ask a question. I recommend for you to visit the SO [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and carefully review at least the following topics: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

without knowing much about your desired action, try this:

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\Users\user\Downloads\file.txt"

foreach ($line in $file) {
    if ($line -match "Pending Device") {
        Write-Host "Reached 'Pending Device'" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "No 'Pending Device' yet"
    }
}
```

Comment: My file.txt contains list of server and devices. I want to read the file to get only the server list which are listed above the line "Pending Device" and ignore rest of the lines below "Pending Device".

Comment: Try to use an array (or whatever variable-type you prefer) to store all data in. If you reached `Pending Device` use the `break` command to jump out of the `foreach`